Asus laptop F555L - changed battery - No WiFi now
I tried to make good use of an old Asus F555L laptop by installing Linux Mint (latest MATE) (full install - no dual boot)
After installing it (everything worked well) I noticed that the battery was starting to inflate (!) so I removed it and changed it with a new one and everything went fine, but after changing it I am no longer able to connect to wifi - I don't know why.
I am pretty sure that before the connection worked. Cable connection works fine.
What Can I do?
Thank you

Like the answer says, re-seat the WiFi card and make sure the antennae are properly secured and then check the firmware (UEFI) settings as it may appear as disabled there. The battery of your laptop is NOT user replaceable, even following accurate guides like iFixit's assumes you know what you're doing. It seems unlikely in this case otherwise you'd have mentioned you re-checked the connections, wouldn't you?

I'd give odds that the WiFi chip or antenna were unplugged or loosened, but two other possibilities are that with no battery or AC power, some firmware setting was lost, or that the WiFi card was damaged, e.g., by short or electrostatic discharge, during battery replacement.
Two things you might try, if trying to reseat the WiFi card and antenna fail:

Boot from USB with Mint Live, and see if it can connect via WiFi. If that works, try reinstalling Mint on the main drive.
Try an inexpensive WiFi USB adapter. A search on Amazon shows them for US$7 and up. [An advantage of an external adapter is that it can be put on a short USB extension and moved to optimize signal.]


I thank you for your answer; actually there was at least 1 problem: as you said the BIOS lost the date during the replacement and I had to set it again; apart from that I actually have been able to solve the issue... just by turning off and on again my home router (!) Don't ask me why ;)
The hint about the using an antenna was neat, though. I actually own an old external wi-fi dongle that would have been one resort if anything else failed.
